# not passing right Parameters in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to create a horizontal scroll view inside a listView. My main activity uses xml containing listview. It calls a custom adapter which extends a base adapter. This custom adapter inflates a xml containing HorizontalListview and getView method calls another adapter.

THis is my custom Adapter that inflates a xml containing a TextView and a HorizontalListView. I call an adapter for the HorizontalListView inside the getView, in which i pass in my activity, and I also pass in the array of items.  When I run my application the customAdapter works fine and I get the right views, but my HorizontalListView doesn't show up at all. I don't think I'm passing in the right parameters. I thought passing the activity would be good, but I guess not.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LinearLayout lg = (LinearLayout) convertView;

    if(lg == null) {
        lg = (LinearLayout)firstInflator.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.hlv1 = (HorizontalListView)lg.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lg.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)lg.getTag();
    }
    mVideos = dA.mShows.get(categories[position]);
    holder.hlv1.setAdapter(new HorizontalGalleryAdapter(dA, mVideos));
    ((TextView) lg.getChildAt(0)).setText(categories[position]);

    return lg;  
}
```

THis is my HorizontalGalleryAdapter. My problem is that only the first adapter is working properly.

```
private final LayoutInflater mInflator;
private ArrayList<Video> mVideos;
private final ImageDownloader mDownload = new ImageDownloader();

public HorizontalGalleryAdapter(DataActivity da, ArrayList<Video>mVideos){
    mInflator = da.getLayoutInflater();
    this.mVideos = mVideos;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView; 
    LinearLayout lg = (LinearLayout)convertView;
    if(lg == null) {
        lg = (LinearLayout)mInflator.inflate(R.layout.third_layout,null);
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) lg.getChildAt(0);
    mDownload.download(mVideos.get(position).mThumb.toString(), imageView);
    ((TextView) lg.getChildAt(1)).setText(mVideos.get(position).mTitle);       
    return lg;
}
```

This is my xml for the HorizontalListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#000000"
   android:id="@+id/second">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textStyle="bold"/> 

<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
   android:id="@+id/listview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#808080">
</com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The parameters are fine. It would crash if there was something wrong with them. You problem is most likely in your layout XML.

Comment: @zapl hey Zapl. i have inserted my xml...could you guide me in the right direction if you notice anything wrong with my xml.

Comment: Try replacing `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in `LinearLayout` with e.g. `android:layout_height="50dp"` the layout it is in has AFAIK no minimal height and that might cause it to be hidden.

Comment: @zapl thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately that didn't work for me. The problem that I thought I had was that in my "getVIew" i'm not using the correct convertView (if that makes any sense) on the secondAdapter but I may be wrong

Comment: It looks okay. If the `convertView` was wrong you should get a crash, for example because you try to get an imageview that should not exist in outer adapter's view.

Comment: you know how I do ((TextView) lg.getChildAt(0)).setText(categories[position]); on my customAdapter? should I do something like lg.getChildAt(1)).add(HorizontalListView) that's not the correct syntax, but  I just don't think the HorizontalListView is being added to the right place

Comment: It seems that my HorizontalListView is just not being inflated to the correct location, because if I try to use the HorizontalListVIewAdapter by itself everything runs smoothly